# Designing Computer Science experiments (Hypotheses and errors?)

Tags: experiment-design

For my master thesis I want to set-up several experiments. One thing my professor has been complaining about is that most computer science experiments are lacking scientifically. To not fall into this trap I want to properly design my experiments. Unfortunately I could not find much literature on CS experiment design. (Except for D. Feitelson's "Experimental Computer Science: The Need for a Cultural Change" available [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~feit/pub.html) which is more of an appeal than a guide.)

I remember that in statistics people often use a H_0 and H_1 hypothesis together with the Type I and Type II error. I wonder if this is applicable in the field of computer science.

A quick example that I could think of:

> H_0: Both methods create the same output in this scenario
>
> H_1: One method creates a worse output in this scenario (worse: according to
>   metric X)

But then how would I calculate the Type I and Type II errors? In a speed-benchmark I could run the experiments multiple times and then possibly calculate how likely it is that the benchmark result is still wrong. However often I just want to compare the output of two deterministic methods. Measuring the quality according to a certain metric. This result doesn't change when running the experiment multiple times. What do I do then? Is the null hypothesis approach not a good fit for these kind of experiments?

Comment: You need to differentiate *study design* (the logic guiding how you get your data) from *statistical analysis* (what inferences you make based on your observed data and study design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what kind of computer experiments you are trying to do. If you are trying to judge the performance of algorithms, there is now a field called *experimental algorithmics* which has [a textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521173019), [journals](http://www.jea.acm.org), and conferences. If you're comparing the performance of two or more algorithms on different inputs, you should probably look at references from this field; this is exactly the kind of thing they study, and they have figured out ways to do this which work much better than the naive first approach that you might think of. Furthermore, the fact that you are following the techniques of an established subfield of computer science should address your professor's complaints that the experiments are lacking scientifically. Even if the experimental design you come up with after looking at the techniques in this field is the same as the one you would have come up on your own, your professor is less likely to object to it.

If you just have two algorithms you want to compare, one input, and one output for each algorithm, there is very little statistical analysis you can do, as this scenario gives you only two data points, and without some kind of model for the behavior of these algorithms, there is absolutely nothing you can do statistically with two data points.

Comment: On the other hand, if "input" and the associated "output" are interpreted as *subject*, and there's lots of different possible inputs and outputs, then algorithm becomes like group or treatment, right? While CS has historically been interested in boundaries and limits of performance, in some applications those things are of more theoretical interest, since most inputs and outputs are located inside some continuum.

Comment: @Alexis: there are some issues you have to worry about with experimental algorithms that you don't with traditional "subjects" and "treatments". In particular, there are lots more ways of choosing inputs than there usually are of choosing "subjects".

Comment: Yes, but you generally do not have only two data points. As an example: assessing different sorting algorithm performance based on a sample of inputs with different orderings. And, with due respect, there are virtually infinite ways of choosing human subjects (with implications for study generalizability), so epidemiologic design (my area) is perhaps not as simple as you imply.

Comment: @Alexis: for sorting algorithms, the question is: how do you choose the inputs? If you just test your algorithm on random inputs, then you may find to your surprise that it works very badly on nearly-sorted inputs. And if you test your algorithm on both randomized and nearly-sorted inputs, how do you know there isn't another class of inputs on which the algorithm works very badly. I have experience with an algorithm which worked well on most classes of inputs, but when you used as a subroutine for a different, the inputs it received made it incredibly slow for reasons we never figured out.

Comment: Well, if one does not assume that one knows the degree of shuffling *a priori*, then experimental design might, if something about the distribution of inputs is known, produce results that characterize the distribution of outputs in a manner that is useful when evaluating relative performance of different algorithms. My point still stands: you generally would not have two data points.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The algorithms I am looking at create a mesh with certain properties from an input geometry. There are of course a lot of possible inputs possible in this case and for each input there is only one output. What I'm trying to do is input a geometry which I know has a certain problem point (for example a very narrow part) and then see how the algorithms handle it (if the narrow part has not disappeared due to incorrect sampling). I have some measures like the area of the input and output geometry which should ideally be the same but these are all 'single unrelated numbers'.

Comment: @RoyT: in this case, what you can do is choose several inputs which have the same kind of problem point, and do statistics on these, so you can get more than two data points so as to do statistics.

Comment: Can I add that, even if you were testing randomized algorithms, choosing just one input instance and comparing two algorithms with multiple runs of the algorithm would be a very bad idea; while you might get something that is "statistically significant", you would have no idea whether the conclusions you come to hold for other instances of the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at Catherine McGeoch's book, "A Guide To Experimental Algorithmics"  McGeoch has been criticized for her work on a study of the performance of the D-wave quantum computer, but I think the book is a good source.

[http://www.amazon.com/Guide-Experimental-Algorithmics-Catherine-McGeoch/dp/0521173019](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521173019)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know this field exists! After Googling I also found this related question in the Stack Exchange network: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/822/a-reading-list-on-experimental-algorithmics